# What's the rule saying on how to serve in Badminton?

Tags: rules, technique, badminton, serve

I'm an amateur and I don't know all the rules in Badminton.

I was serving the ***backhand low service***. Now someone told me that I have to hit the shuttle after I have fully release it.

I debated with him that is totally impossible to serve if I have **not fully** released the shuttle.

Again he told me that I'm releasing the shuttle at the last moment, not giving enough time to release the shuttle *entirely*.

Now I want to know:

> Is there any rule that says that I have to give minimum *x* amount of
> time to release the shuttle entirely before serving?
>
> Or what is the minimum time to serve after realising the shuttle?

I was practicing it like told in the [Youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4m-kVx4K8cg) and I'm pretty sure I was doing as much possible exactly like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### LAWS OF BADMINTON

According to the official *[LAWS OF BADMINTON (2012)](http://bwfbadminton.org/file.aspx?id=516821&dl=1)*, set by the [Badminton World Federation](http://bwfbadminton.org/default.aspx), chapter 9 is applicable: *SERVICE*.

In that chapter, no reference can be found of the fact that a specific time interval needs to be taken into account or that the shuttle needs to be fully released.

The following is to mention about "taking your time":

> 9.1.1 neither side shall cause undue delay to the delivery of the service once the server and the   receiver are ready for the service.
>   On completion of the backward movement of server’s   racket head, any
>   delay in the start of the service (Law 9.2), shall be considered to be
>   an undue   delay;

and in chapter 16, this is restricted:

> 16.6.1 deliberately cause delay in, or suspension of, play;

In hitting the shuttle, these two paragraphs are to be followed:

> 9.1.4 the server’s racket shall initially hit the base of the shuttle;
>   ...
>   9.1.8 the flight of the shuttle shall be upwards from the server’s racket to pass over the net so that,   if not intercepted, it shall
>   land in the receiver’s service court (i. e. on or within the boundary 
>   lines);

If you do the above (with or without holding the shuttle), then you're safe !!

PS: I've just tried hitting a shuttle by holding it: that's merely impossible, without smashing your fingers.....